# How to fix Indent error in pug + Nuxt 3 + vite?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, pug, vite, nuxtjs3

I have this error
when i did indent in template vue,
but without indent it work correct and i don't get the error

```
>   > 2|   WrapperGlobal
> -------^
>     3|     v-container.fill-height
>     4|       h1
>     5|       |  {{ error }}
```

and i know that vue 3 has ugly parse this template
and i found the solution by @webdiscus/pug-loader.
but i don't now hot to configuration in nuxt.config.ts
it is example

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const pugRule = config.module.rule('pug');

    // clear all existing pug loaders
    pugRule.uses.clear();
    pugRule.oneOfs.clear();
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          oneOf: [
            // allow import of Pug in JavaScript
            {
              exclude: /\.vue$/,
              loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader',
              options: {
                method: 'compile', // compile Pug into template function
              },
            },
            // allow <template lang="pug"> in Vue components
            {
              loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader',
              options: {
                method: 'html', // render Pug into pure HTML string
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

but i have this file
and pls help set this config in my file

```
import i18n from './configs/i18n'
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    ],
    css: [
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
        'assets/sass/main.sass'
    ],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
    },
    plugins: ['~/plugins/core.js'],
    i18n,
    
    // nitro: {
    //  devProxy: {
    //      '/api': {
    //          target: '',
    //          changeOrigin: true,
    //          secure: false,
    //          ws: true,
    //      }
    //  },
    // },
})
```

Comment: Is there something on line 1 of that file that isn't indented? If not, why are you starting a file indented a level?